# Remove redundant scopes in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is it possible to remove redundant scopes in PhpStorm?

Sometimes I search in directories, - but when I want to 'go back to my default search-setting (using my custom scope), then I have to press 'Scope' and scroll to the bottom and select it. Can I remove all the other ones (in the blue box below), since I never use them anyway?

[image: phpstorm-scopes]

---

### Edit1

Or is it possible to make a shortcut to search in a custom scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those scopes are a standard feature of the product and cannot be removed.